# trying to print transpose string[]

Tags: java, file, arraylist

So i've been trying to take a txt file which has input like this for eg -

```
abcddhdj
efghdd
ijkl
```

to get this -

```
j
d
hd
dd
dhl
cgk
bfj
aei
```

i have tried to do this using 2d char array which gave nullexception and arrayoutofbound error and didnt work mostly,then tried string array , arraylist of arraylist of char , and lastly i have been trying using arraylsit of string

here is the closest i got to my solution after lot of searching by using string[] -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\test.txt"));         // PUT YOUR FILE LOCATION HERE
    int k=0,i,j=0,x;
    String line[] = new String[10] ;     //SET THE APPROXIMATE NUMBER OF ROWS
    while((line[k] = br.readLine()) !=null)
        {System.out.println(line[k]);      //print to check input - verified
         k++;


        }
    for(x=0;x<k;x++)
    {if(j<line[x].length())
       {j=line[x].length()-1;}    //this part not working in above loop
    }
    System.out.println(j);    // verified but not working inside previous loop for some reason
    System.out.println(k);


    for(x=j-1;x>=0;x++)         //without this loop,its perfect, but with it gives  indexoutofbound error , doesnt run at x=j
    {  for(i=0;i<k;i++)
       { System.out.print(line[i].charAt(x));
       } 
       System.out.println();
    }

}
```

here is one output

```
run:
﻿abcd
efgh
ijkl
4     //should have come as 3 since i did length-1
3
chl     //notice the d missing , every char of first row shifted,just why
bgk    //in outofbound error , it only prints d at the end, need explanation 
afj
ei
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

if i add a space after abcd it gives indexoutofbound and no output after k
at end i used another method which adds spaces to make all length equal
yet still the output was wrong, plus there is something wrong with this way of thinking , there should be better method

so i tried arraylist , this is giving me more problems again

trying to work this out by any method understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to do the trick:

The key here is that I pad all the line arrays with empty chars so that each character array is the same length as the longest line.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\test.txt")))
    {
        String line;
        List<List<Character>> lines = new ArrayList<>();

        int longestLine = 0;
        while((line = br.readLine()) !=null)
        {
            line = line.trim();

            if (line.length() > 0)
            {
                List<Character> currList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (char c : line.toCharArray())
                {
                    currList.add(c);
                }

                if (currList.size() > longestLine)
                {
                    longestLine = currList.size();
                }

                lines.add(currList);
            }
        }

        // pad all lists to be the same as the longest
        for (List<Character> currList : lines)
        {
            while (currList.size() < longestLine)
            {
                currList.add(Character.MIN_VALUE);
            }
        }

        // go through each list backwards
        for (int i = longestLine - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
        {
            for (List<Character> currList : lines)
            {
                System.out.print(currList.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    catch (Throwable t)
    {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Example Input**:

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
g
```

**Example Output**:

```
dhl
cgk
bfj
aeig
```

Comment: i still have the problem that the elements of line 1 in input are shifted by one space in output

Comment: for input -
abcd 
efgh
ijkl   g
output is
g


d
chl
bgj
afj
ei

Comment: @RAK For the input: 
abcd
efgh
ijkl
g

The output should be: 
dhl
cgk
bfj
aeig

Comment: yes but its not giving that but the one in comment i gave above

Comment: @RAK not sure why you are getting that output. I will update my post to clarify the input/output

Answer (score 0):

Assuming input is read into the arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> inputList = new ArrayList<String>();
inputList.add("abcddhdj");
inputList.add("efghdd");
inputList.add("ijkl");

int maxSize = 0;
for (String input : inputList) {
    if (input.length() > maxSize) {
        maxSize = input.length();
    }
}
String outputList[] = new String[maxSize];
for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
    String output = "";
    for (String input : inputList) {
      if(i<input.length())
          output=output+input.charAt(i);
    }
    outputList[maxSize-(i+1)]=output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store all to direct 2d array and transpose in printing loop

```
    final char[][] matrix = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName)).map(String::toCharArray).toArray(char[][]::new);
    final int width = Arrays.stream(matrix).mapToInt(a -> a.length).max().getAsInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i ) {
        final int idx = width-i-1;
        String s = Arrays.stream(matrix).map(a -> a.length > idx ? String.valueOf(a[idx]) : " ").collect(Collectors.joining());
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Comment: i tried changing the filename in first line with test.txt or C:\\test.txt but it didnt work , please tell how to put the filename

Comment: umm i already said it doesnt work, it gives -  error: cannot find symbol and error: invalid method reference

Comment: it mean missed imports. add "import java.nio.file.*"